# coffee blend simultaneous equation

Tags: systems-of-equations

A coffee distributor has two types of coffee. The premium blend sells

for $\$10.50$ per kg and the standard blend sells for $\$8.25$ per kg.

The distributor wishes to create 20 kg of a mixture containing these two blends to sell at $9 per kg.

Determine how many kg of each blend should be in the mixture?

Attempt:
Let the mass of the premium coffee be x kg and the standard coffee be y kg.

x+y = 20 (equation 1)

10.5x + 8.25y = 180  (equation 2)

Is the second set of equation set up correctly?

Comment: Yes, this looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is correct.
$\frac{(10.5x+8.25y)}{20}=9$
so $10.5x+8.25y=9*20=180$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have corrected your formatting. Honestly, considering, this question does not really required to be answered (can be done in comments), unless one wants to provide some proper insight that may be useful